# how to send user recipient address to the browser link?

Tags: php, jquery, email, zend-framework

I am developing one application in php zend with sql server 2008, jquery and ajax.

I need to send an email with my webpage link to a specific client and need to get feedback from him.

I can send one email containing that link it it to that client.

But i need to do some security to this :

- If the user click on the email link than only he should be able to see the webpage. Means if he copy the link and paste it to the browser than he should not be able to see the webpage.
- If the client forward the email to someone else than also the other person should not be able to see the webpage.

Means only the person should be able to see the webpage through the link only.

How can i check the recipient email address in email and send it to the webpage as a query string or something ?

Or is there any way to do this ?

can anyone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

If you really need to secure the website from your client you might want to build some kind of token system. The client calls you for a token which is only valid for a limited time and has to enter it to view your site.

Comment: ohhh.. Is there any way to check the recipient's address ??

Comment: to check the valid user

Comment: You mean if someone clicked a link to your site in the mail? Then no. The mail client doesn't do anything special. It calls the browser to open th url. Nothing that would identify the recipient of the mail and nothing that would prevent the recipient from forwarding your mail.

Answer (score 1):

not possible, you can force client to log in, but he can also pass his credentials as well. You cannot hide any link in email that cannot be copied.